# Can grant command in mysql create a new user?

Tags: mysql, sql, account

Can grant command in mysql create a new user?

Comment: The command itself can't. Granting an existing user the right permissions lets *them* do it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) on the GRANT syntax, you'll see a section regarding **Privileges Supported by MySQL** that mentions all the permissions you can grant including [CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-user):

> CREATE USER
>
> Enable use of CREATE USER, DROP USER, RENAME USER, and REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES. Level: Global.